# Failed to get properties: No such interface '' in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 16.04, services

I Created this Unit file `tdk-api.service` in the `/etc/systemd/system` folder with this permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x`

with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description = tdk API daemon

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart =  /usr/local/bin/start-tdk-api.sh
ExecStop =   /usr/local/bin/stop-tdk-api.sh
ExecReload = /usr/local/bin/reload-tdk-api.sh

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

But I have an error when starting:

```
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# sudo systemctl start tdk-api
Failed to start tdk-api.service: Unknown unit: tdk-api.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status tdk-api.service' for details.
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status tdk-api.service
Failed to get properties: No such interface ''
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system#
```

I also tried to reload systemd daemon, as suggested

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

I also tried:

```
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl enable tdk-api.service
Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/tdk-api.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tdk-api.service, pointing to /etc/systemd/system/tdk-api.service.
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# sudo systemctl start tdk-api
Failed to start tdk-api.service: Unknown unit: tdk-api.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status tdk-api.service' for details.
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status tdk-api.service
Failed to get properties: No such interface ''
```

Comment: the systemctl file works, the error is in to the sh scripts. I try out the same systemctl file with some script just perform an echo and it works.

Comment: Faced with the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. After doing numerous attempts with restarting systemd, the problem was fixed just after restart the system at all sudo reboot After complete reboot broken service started work as expected. P.S. Uptime of system was more than 1 year and during that period were done upgrade of packages and probably systemd. That's could be a reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in start-tdk-api.sh.  I'm guessing either an environment variable is not set (like PATH) or you're not executing in the directory you think you're in.

You can set environment variables in the service file or update the PATH variable in the script (probably the easiest).

You can also set the working directory for the script in the service file:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/directory/to/run/from
```